# Including properties with nil values when serializing with JSONModel

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, serialization, jsonmodel

I am serializing a custom class in Objective-C using [JSONModel](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel). The class `User` that I am trying to serialize looks like:

```
<User> 
   [UserCount]: 658
   [CreationDate]: 2014-04-17T00:38:34.176Z
   [Credits]: 0
   [Email]: Email Address
   [Locale]: <nil>
   [DeveloperDetails]: <nil>
   [Name]: ashishagarwal
   [UserName]: ashishagarwal
   [_id]: xxxxxxxx--userid--------------
   [FirstName]: First Name
   [AuthenticationType]: <nil>
   [_deleted]: 0
   [LastActivityDate]: 2015-02-10T23:26:41.816Z
   [Type]: 0
   [IsAuthenticated]: 0
   [LastName]: Last Name
   [LastLoginDate]: 2015-02-12T03:39:50.626Z
</User>
```

There are a few `nil` values, but that's expected.

I am trying to serialize using the line:

```
id json = [self.currentUser toJSONString];
```

The JSON, when printed out is:

```
{
    "UserCount": 658,
    "CreationDate": "2014-04-17T00:38:34.176Z",
    "Credits": 0,
    "Email": "Email Address",
    "Name": "ashishagarwal",
    "UserName": "ashishagarwal",
    "_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "FirstName": "First Name",
    "_deleted": false,
    "LastActivityDate": "2015-02-10T23:26:41.816Z",
    "Type": 0,
    "IsAuthenticated": false,
    "LastLoginDate": "2015-02-12T03:39:50.626Z",
    "LastName": "Last Name"
}
```

The values that were `nil` have disappeared. Is there a way to have them marked as "null" when serializing ?

Comment: Have you marked these as `<Optional>`?!? Otherwise, they will be included. Show us how you've defined the properties of your `User` class.

Answer (score 0):

[As noted by Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28470511/including-properties-with-nil-values-when-serializing-with-jsonmodel#comment45266125_28470511), it matters whether the property is marked as `Optional` or not.

If a property is marked as `Optional`, and the value is `nil`, the key is not outputted in the resulting JSON. If you remove the `Optional` flag, it will be outputted as `null`.

We are considering making a change such that when an `Optional` property is explicitly set as `NSNull`, the value will be outputted as `null`. [See this issue](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/issues/348) - once it is resolved, you will be able to do the following:

```
self.currentUser.DeveloperDetails = [NSNull null];
NSString *json = [self.currentUser toJSONString];
```